# yahoo finance api returns empty response

Tags: yql, yahoo-finance

My application showing stock market data. I am using YQL for fetching stock data.

[http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22SBIN.NS%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&diagnostics=true&format=xml](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22SBIN.NS%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&diagnostics=true&format=xml)

Lats two days, When I am fetching morning or before (1.00 pm India time)  then yql query returns empty response. 
But right now it show exact problem

The query result is "yahoo.finance.quotes' has been blocked.

Response is

```
    <query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="0" yahoo:created="2012-09-26T11:24:22Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <diagnostics>
    <publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
    <url execution-start-time="20" execution-stop-time="23" execution-time="3" proxy="DEFAULT">
    <![CDATA[
    http://www.datatables.org/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.quotes.xml
    ]]>
    </url>
    <cache execution-start-time="25" execution-stop-time="26" execution-time="1" method="GET" type="MEMCACHED">
    <![CDATA[ 13c4f8eac77ad886bade5a711c8c1ef5 ]]>
    </cache>
    <javascript name="yahoo.finance.quotes" verb="select">
    <![CDATA[
    com.yahoo.platforms.pipes.model.ModuleException: Error Codes: js.blocked.execute.request Message: "The current table 'yahoo.finance.quotes' has been blocked. It exceeded the allotted quotas of either time or instructions"
    ]]>
    </javascript>
    <user-time>26</user-time>
    <service-time>4</service-time>
    <build-version>30549</build-version>
    </diagnostics>
    <results/>
    </query>
```

I am not exceed request limit 1000\hours. Just try in day 50 times.

Answer (score 4):

"This is a community contributed table and used by multiple people. We mark a table as abusive if it seems to be hogging our resources, or consistently taking more than 30s to execute (this could also be due to a slow downstream source). This particular table seems to be getting marked as abusive more times than others. We also remove our blocks after a while, hence the sporadic working of the table. I would advise that you wait for official tables from Yahoo! Finance if your application needs a stabler data source."

http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/YQL/YQL-The-current-table-39-yahoo-finance-quotes-39-has/1332611837865-68d31e89-80e4-4691-91e6-86f687302ff4